# Sweave-LaTeX file: use a new font in text but keep original font for R code

Tags: r, fonts, latex, sweave

Using Sweave I wrote a file a little test file, which shown below. 
As I want to use different fonts, I load the package `fontspec`. 
In the .pdf output also the `R` code chunks show a new font, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} % fonts

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

% new font
\fontspec{Cambria}    
Some text. 

% R chunk
<< >>=
x <- 1:10
plot(x)
@

\end{document}
```

My question: 
Is it possible, (maybe with `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{}`?), to return to the default font for the `R` code chunks, keeping the font as in `\fontspec{ }` for the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was harder than I had expected. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600050/how-can-i-change-fonts-in-a-beamer-presentation-that-uses-sweave). The magic line seems to be `\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}`.

I've made a few changes because `\usepackage{fontspec}` seems to expect something other than pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
\usepackage[light,math]{anttor} % Obvious and ugly roman font. 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}


% new font
Some text. 


% R chunk
<< >>=
x <- 1:10
plot(x)
@

\end{document}
```